# How to set bounds and flyToBounds using svelte-map-leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, svelte

Recently I'm started using Svelte and I want to add a map to my project. I choose leaflet in svelte-map-leaflet package.

Unfortunately I don't know how to set bounds and flyToBound (like in my old project) because I don't have access to "L" variable.

Anybody has idea how to solve this problem? Should I move to standard leaflet package?

Thanks for any advice

Regards Matt